# Where is the ASP Character component panel - Unreal Engine

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am studying game development in college with Unreal Engine and found this book on the internet: **[Blueprints Visual Scripting for Unreal Engine](https://pt.scribd.com/book/274184808/Blueprints-Visual-Scripting-for-Unreal-Engine)**

I kept doing it step by step, until **chapter 5**

[image: book]

I find this object: ***Ue4ASP_Character***

[image: object]

Here is the problem

[image: the book problem]

***Has no panel components***

[image: where is the panel components]

Comment: If you look in the top right of your last picture, you see that the parent class is UObject, so somehow you didn't select Ue4ASP_Character, but 'Object' instead. delete your blueprint and retry the step where you select the parent class

Comment: I highly suggest you try the resources at the Unreal Engine Academy. They are free and cover most of these topics. In this case as @BasinhetVeld commented, your Blueprint's parent class is Object. Not sure how that lesson is developing but is that Ue4ASP_Character a base for all your enemies? Also, keep in mind that book is from 2015, UE4 changed A LOT since then.

Comment: @Fritz The problem with the Unreal Engine Academy is that they are videos and are in English, my English is good enough to be able to read a PDF and translate some words, but in a video it gets more complicated. **@BasinhetVeld** And as you can see in the penultimate image, there is only one object to select, that's what I selected. Perhaps the pdf object no longer exists.